# Apparently the SDK is encoding text, how to avoid?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the SDK to post to FB wall, what happen is if I post a text like:

> Hello "world"!

In the FB wall I get the following:

> Hello \"world\"!

Why is happening? What should I do to avoid that?

Below is a sample of the code I use, where of course the query string parameters returned by Request.Get may contain anything, if there's a string with " or a carriage return, etc... After the code is executed I can see on my FB wall the post with the encoded chars.

```
FacebookClient fbc = new FacebookClient( _accesstoken_ );

dynamic ievent = new ExpandoObject();
ievent.name = Request.Get("name");
ievent.description = Request.Get("description");
ievent.location = Request.Get("location");
ievent.privacy_type = Request.Get("privacy");

dynamic result = fbc.Post("me/events", ievent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out was a bug in the C# FB SDK.

After downloading the latest release everything worked fine.